# Unbalanced column length in multicol

Tags: multicol

I use the `multicol` package with a simple `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}`. Yet on the bottom of certain pages LuaLaTeX cannot balance out the vertical length of the columns, which looks quite ugly in my humble view. I use `\setlength{\parskip}{3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}` to add some flexibility, but still no avail, and I do not get any warnings or bad boxes either. See a similar example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[3]\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]\lipsum[6]\lipsum[7]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What preferences should I use to prevent such outcome?

Comment: Without data to test it on, we can only guess.  I would worry more about the end of the right column than the left column.  `\usepackage{showframe}` would help here.

Comment: Ah, left column it is.  One thing you should know is that multicols puts both columns into one savebox and uses \vsplit to break it into two (or more) columns at the end of the page.

Comment: you have a parskip of 3pt so naturally after each paragraph lines in one column are 3pt shifted compared to the other column, so what you show seems quite expected, but as you have shown no code, impossible to really say more.

Comment: \raggedbottom in force perhaps? together with your parskip setting that may explains it, but without a real MWE nothing really to go on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

There is no flexibility in the first column so no possibility to make the final line at the nominal `\textheight` position as `\textheight` is not `\topskip`  plus a multiple of `\baselineskip`.

The `geometry` package has a `heightrounded` option to fix `\textheight` so a page full of pure paragraph lines does fit the page. so using

```
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe,heightrounded]{geometry}
```

produces the output above.

Comment: I've tried to figure out from the code how does it work, but I couldn't. Does it increase the top-, the bottomskip or the baselineskip?

Comment: @Kazibácsi it rounds `\textheight` so `\textheight` - `\topskip` is a multiple of `\baselineskip`

Comment: OK, so the extra `textheight` is not compensated at the bottom, and the page number is shifted downwards a bit.